# automatically close excel userform when change sheet

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform that automatically appears when a new sheet is created from a pivot table drilldown. I am trying to figure out how to have this userform automically close if the user navigates to any other sheet in the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SheetActivate` event of the `Workbook` object to check the name of the worksheet that is active and take action accordingly.  For example:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" And UserForm1.Visible Then
        Unload UserForm1
    End If
End Sub
```

This event is available in the `ThisWorkbook` module of your Excel Workbook. I believe your UserForm will need to be Modeless for users to be able to change sheets while the form is visible.

You can read about the [Workbook.SheetActivate Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195710(v=office.15).aspx) here.